# Checked Exception 2 kinds of behaviours

Tags: java, exception, checked

I have noticed that there are 2 kinds of checked exceptions:

**1)**

```
public static void main (String []args)
{
    try{
        //no exception thrown here, it still compiles though.
    }
    catch(Exception e){System.out.println(e);}
}
```

**2)**

```
public static void main (String []args)
{
    try{
         // it does not compile if not written any code which potentially might throw it
    }
    catch(IOException io){System.out.println(io);}
}
```

Is there any rule to anticipate this behaviour? to know in advance which is not mandatory to be present and it is? 
Hope I have been quite clear with explaining the issue.
Thanks,
Indeed ItIs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Java Language specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-11.html#jls-11.2.3) states

> It is a compile-time error if a catch clause can catch checked
>   exception class E1 and it is not the case that the try block
>   corresponding to the catch clause can throw a checked exception class
>   that is a subclass or superclass of E1, **unless E1 is Exception or a
>   superclass of Exception.**

Comment: I believe the reason for this is because `Exception` includes the run-time exceptions.  This is what I was trying to say in my answer.  Is that not the case?

Comment: @NickC Exception might be the superclass of all unchecked exceptions, but it is not itself an unchecked exception.  It is a checked exception.

Comment: Correct, I am not saying that it is.  I'm suggesting that it appears the reason for the clause in your answer is because it is the superclass of all run-time exceptions; so it cannot compute compile-time analysis on whether `Exception` can be caught or not.

Comment: @nickC It can if you call a method that is declared as `throws Exception`, otherwise it follows the JLS.

Comment: Now you've lost me.  It can know if it *is* possible, but the compiler cannot be sure that it's *not* possible.

Comment: @NickC Maybe I misunderstood/read what you were saying. Undelete your answer.

Answer (score 3):

The code compiles fine with `Exception`, because it is a super class of all *Checked* and *Unchecked* exceptions. So, a `catch` clause with `Exception` can handle the *unchecked exception* too. And for *Unchecked exception*, compiler cannot check at compile time that the exception is thrown or not. So, it won't give any error for `Exception`.

You can even try this with `RuntimeException`:

```
try {

} catch (RuntimeException e) {

}
```

... this will compile too.

From [JLS Section 11.2.3 - Exception Checking](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-11.html#jls-11.2.3):

> It is a compile-time error if a catch clause can catch checked exception class E1 and it is not the case that the try block corresponding to the catch clause can throw a checked exception class that is a subclass or superclass of E1, unless E1 is Exception or a superclass of Exception.

Comment: Yes but `Exception` is not an unchecked exception. If it was thrown in the body, you would still have to catch it.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis. Yeah true. But it can handle the unchecked exception too. I said, it's a super class of all checked and unchecked exception. This compiles for the reason of unchecked subclass exceptions.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis. I'm searching for the precise reason in JLS, will post it if found.

Comment: See my answer below and http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-11.html#jls-11.1.1

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis. OOPs, missed your comment, while I was editing.

Comment: It'll be easier for OP to understand with redundancy.

Answer (score 2):

`Exception` is a checked exception itself, but is also the superclass for `RuntimeException` and other unchecked exceptions.

**1)** In the first case, because the `Exception` class hierarchy includes `RunTimeException`, the compiler cannot conclude that an `Exception` will *not* be thrown in your `try { ... }` block.  So, it must allow the code.

It can confirm the positive case (if you call a method that declares `throws Exception` or a non-run-time subclass), but it cannot confirm the negative case.

**2)** In the second case, it *can* conclude at compile-time that `IOException` will not be thrown in the `try { ... }` block, because `IOException` (nor any other checked exception besides `Exception` itself) is not the superclass for any run-time exceptions.

---

Of the following behaviors, I believe that `Exception` is the only special case with a combination of the two types:

If thrown:
**1A.** Does not need to be declared *or*
**1B.** Must be declared

If declared:
**2A.** Does not need to be thrown *or*
**2B.** Must be thrown

If not thrown:
**3A.** May be caught *or*
**3B.** Must not be caught

- RuntimeException: **1A**, **2A**, **3A**
- Any other checked exception: **1B**, **2B**, **3B**
- Exception: **1B**, **2A**, **3A**

---

More info on checked vs. unchecked exceptions in this answer:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/6116020/143295

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Thank you, I am updating my answer to clarify that `Exception` itself is checked but is the parent class for unchecked exceptions, following our comments on your answer.  Good answer btw.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Thank you, I learned something today.  I updated my answer to describe the situation I was seeing when I ran test code.